# SQL Server Stored Procedure: select col1, if @variable is not null col2

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have an SQL Server stored procedure to which I want to extend to incorporate a distance search.

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM table
WHERE ......
```

The stored procedure has variables for @Longitude and @Latitude. If these have been passed in, I want to  return a distance, otherwise return 9999999. I've tried:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4,
IF @Latitude IS NOT NULL AND @Longitude IS NOT NULL 
                3956 * 2 * ASIN(
                  SQRT( POWER(SIN((@Latitude - abs(dest.Latitude)) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) 
                      + COS(@Longitude * pi()/180 ) * COS(abs(dest.Latitude) * pi()/180)  
                      * POWER(SIN((@Longitude - dest.Longitude) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) 
                  AS Distance
            ELSE
                9999999 AS Distance
FROM table
WHERE ......
```

But am getting

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'

Is what I'm attempting to do achievable? Do I need to separate the IF from the body of the SELECT statement somehow? (apologies if this is an elementary question)

Thanks

Comment: I think `case` will does this well instead `if`.

Comment: Use case statement instead of if

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `CASE`

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4,
CASE WHEN @Latitude IS NOT NULL AND @Longitude IS NOT NULL THEN
                3956 * 2 * ASIN(
                  SQRT( POWER(SIN((@Latitude - abs(dest.Latitude)) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) 
                      + COS(@Longitude * pi()/180 ) * COS(abs(dest.Latitude) * pi()/180)  
                      * POWER(SIN((@Longitude - dest.Longitude) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) 
            ELSE
                9999999 
END AS Distance
FROM table
WHERE ......
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `CASE` instead of `IF` in `SELECT` query

```
    SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4,
              CASE WHEN( @Latitude IS NOT NULL AND @Longitude IS NOT NULL )
              THEN
                3956 * 2 * ASIN(
                  SQRT( POWER(SIN((@Latitude - abs(dest.Latitude)) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) 
                      + COS(@Longitude * pi()/180 ) * COS(abs(dest.Latitude) * pi()/180)  
                      * POWER(SIN((@Longitude - dest.Longitude) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) 

            ELSE
                9999999 
            END AS Distance

FROM table
WHERE ......
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do what you are trying to do in SQL is to use `CASE WHEN`:

**Example:**

```
DECLARE @int INT = 1

SELECT  col1 ,
        CASE WHEN @int = 1 THEN 'Yes'
             ELSE 'No'
        END AS YN
FROM    table
```

**[Reference: CASE WHEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)**

The `IF` syntax can be used in functions and stored procedures:

**Example:**

```
DECLARE @int INT = 1

IF @int = 1 
    BEGIN
        SELECT  col1 , 'Yes' AS YN
        FROM    table
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT  col1 , 'No' AS YN
        FROM    table
    END
```

**[Reference: IF.. ELSE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms182717.aspx)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT 
 [col1],
 [col2],
 [col3],
 [col4],
    CASE 
        WHEN 
            @Latitude IS NOT NULL AND 
            @Longitude IS NOT NULL 
        THEN
            3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((@Latitude - abs(dest.Latitude)) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) 
                      + COS(@Longitude * pi()/180 ) 
                      * COS(abs(dest.Latitude) * pi()/180)  
                      * POWER(SIN((@Longitude - dest.Longitude) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) 
        ELSE
             9999999 
    END AS [Distance]
FROM TableName
WHERE ......
```

Example of using IIf in 2012 with comparision:

> IF -1 < 1 THEN ‘TRUE’ ELSE ‘FALSE’

You can just use CASE statement as follows:

```
-- SQL Server 2008 and earlier version solution

SELECT CASE
WHEN -1 < 1 THEN 'TRUE'
ELSE 'FALSE' END AS Result

GO

-- SQL Server 2012 solution

SELECT IIF ( -1 < 1, 'TRUE', 'FALSE' ) AS Result;

GO
```

**Refer for more info**

> Official - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh213574.aspx
>
> Helpfull - http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/09/10/sql-server-denali-logical-function-iif-a-quick-introduction/